# Popup's draggable Area of Movement Limited

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, popup, draggable, non-modal

In my application I am invoking a PopUp by

```
Popup pop = new Popup;
```

then i add this:: `pop.child(page);` where "page" is the instance of a XAML page which is of type **ChildWindow**.
Now when the popup shows up on my MainPage, it becomes Non-Modal just like I want it to be!!
But the problem is, the popup window is not draggable through out the Mainpage. I know that the popup appears within the Boundaries of a Silverlight control hosted in a browser. And It's not a true window. But still my popup is not draggable within its boundaries.. 
Am i missing some declarations which define the draggable region of a popup control OR is it the ChildWindow which needs to be configured ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the issue I had to remove the fixed `Height` and `Width` attributes of the `ChildWindow` and used `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` values and set their values to 4000. Now my `ChildWindow` inside the popup is perfectly draggable throughout the silverlight application.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem. I simply had to set the `Width` and `Height` in the first control (eg `Grid`) of the `ChildWindow` not in the `ChildWindow` itself. Changing `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` did not change anything...